# Can someone explain what all of this means?

Tags: html, json, visual-studio-code

```
   {
       // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
       // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
       // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
       "version": "0.2.0",
       "configurations": [
           {
               "type": "pwa-chrome",
               "request": "launch",
               "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
               "url": "http://localhost:8080",
               "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
           }
       ]
   }
```

I am trying to understand how to run my html file so that it creates a webpage on chrome but I'm not sure what all of this is and if this is correct.

Comment: You could save yourself a whole lot of time if you just learned the basics of HTML first.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you try following [that link](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387) provided in the comments section of the code you pasted above?

Comment: I did but I didn't understand what was going on the page, also I am trying to learn HTML but I couldn't run my file.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I you want to open an html file in chrome right click on the file and select : open with chrome.